# Internet History Script For Google Chrome

Tags: python, matlab, google-chrome

I'm not looking for a "best" or most efficient script to do this. But I was wondering if there exists a script to pull Internet History for a day's time from, say, Google Chrome and log it to a txt file. I'd prefer if it were in Python or MATLAB.

If you guys have a different method using one of these languages utilizing locally stored browser history data from Google Chrome, I'd be all ears for that too.

I'd be super-thankful if anyone could help with this!

Answer (score 5):

From my understanding, it seems easy to be done. I don't know if this is what you want.
Internet history from Chrome is stored at a specific path. Take Win7 for example, it's stored at win7: `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History`

In Python:

```
f = open('C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History', 'rb')
data = f.read()
f.close()
f = open('your_expected_file_path', 'w')
f.write(repr(data))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on what m170897017 said:

That file is an sqlite3 database, so taking `repr()` of its contents won't do anything meaningful.

You need to open the sqlite database and run SQL against it to get the data out. In python use the [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) library in the stdlib to do this.

Here's a related SuperUser question that shows some SQL for getting URLs and timestamps: https://superuser.com/a/694283

Comment: Is this an OK download? [pysqlite 2.6.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite) ?

Comment: Yes that should work. But sqlite is built into python's standard library too. Try this at a python interpreter: "import sqlite3". If that works, you don't need to download a library. See the sqlite3 documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

Dodged sqlite3/sqlite, I'm using the Google Chrome extension "Export History", exporting everything into a CSV file, and subsequently loading that CSV file into cells within MATLAB.

[Export History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/export-history/hcohnnbbiggngobheobhdipbgmcbelhh)

My code turned out to be:

```
file_o = ['history.csv'];
fid = fopen(file_o, 'rt');
fmt = [repmat('%s', 1, 6) '%*[^\n]'];
C = textscan(fid,fmt,'Delimiter',',','CollectOutput',true);
C_unpacked = C{:}; 
C_urls = C_unpacked(1:4199, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one:

```
import csv, sqlite3, os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

connection = sqlite3.connect(os.getenv("APPDATA") + "\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\history")
connection.text_factory = str
cur = connection.cursor()
output_file = open('chrome_history.csv', 'wb')
csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
headers = ('URL', 'Title', 'Visit Count', 'Date (GMT)')
csv_writer.writerow(headers)
epoch = datetime(1601, 1, 1)
for row in (cur.execute('select url, title, visit_count, last_visit_time from urls')):
    row = list(row)
    url_time = epoch + timedelta(microseconds=row[3])
    row[3] = url_time
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you are looking for. However, by using this you can manipulate the database tables to your liking

```
import os
import sqlite3

def Find_path():
    User_profile = os.environ.get("USERPROFILE")
    History_path = User_profile + r"\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History" #Usually this is where the chrome history file is located, change it if you need to.
    return History_path

def Main():
    data_base = Find_path()            
    con = sqlite3.connect(data_base) #Connect to the database
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' ORDER BY name") #Change this to your prefered query
    print(c.fetchall())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```