# Reading the Chrome Bookmarks (JSON) file in Python

Tags: python, json, google-chrome

I am trying to manipulate the Chrome Bookmarks file in Python, but have fallen at the first hurdle.  I have this code:

```
import json
import os

input_filename = os.getenv("APPDATA") + "\..\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\history"

with open(input_filename) as data_file:
    bookmark_data = json.load(data_file)
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/David/PycharmProjects/MyBookmarks/myBookmarks.py", line 17, in <module>
bookmark_data = json.load(data_file)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 290, in load
**kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am not that familiar with JSON, but given this is the chrome bookmarks file, I doubt it is a problem with the structure of the file, and I am stumped as to what to try next! Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you posted says `json.load(data_file)` but the error message says the line is `json.loads(data_file)`.  Note the extra 's'.  You use `loads` if you're reading from a string ("load string") and `load` for reading from a file.  I suspect you have an extra 's' in your actual code.

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614391/internet-history-script-for-google-chrome

Comment: Sorry!  I accidentally had the wrong error cose in my initial posted - have now pasted in the correct one.

Comment: SomeGuyOnAComputer - thanks, but that question relates to the Chrome History file which is a SQLite DB, where as I am wanting to read the Chrome Bookmarks File, which is a JSON file.

Comment: OK - I'm a moron.  I had the path pointing at the history file not the bookmarks file.  Stupid copy and paste!

Answer (score 2):

- **Bookmarks** is the name of the `JSON` file which you want to open
- History is a database file which contains information on URL visits
  and files downloaded

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the encoding worked for me

```
with open(input_filename, "r", encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    bookmark_data = json.load(data_file)
```

Inspiration: https://pypi.org/project/chrome-bookmarks/